# How is the "click to view more" function implemented?

Tags: string, internationalization

We often see websites that display first few lines of an article and then append ... [More] so that people who are interested in can click on it to view the full article.

To implement this functionality, we first need to find out where the article text should be cut to append the ... [More].

Since there must be some HTML/ CSS coupled with the article text, we must remember to ignore them when calculating the length of the text.

But there is something I just can't figure it out, if more than one language is mixed in the first few lines of the article text, the length of the text will be very difficult to calculate since the characters can be of variable length.

How should we solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly where this source is from but I've been using this piece of code, explanations of which you will find in its comments:

```
/**
* @desc Cut given plain/HTML text nicely
* @param string text to cut
* @param int approximetly length of desired text length
* @param int optional length, how far text can variante from approximetly length
* @param bool optional can we cut words
* @param bool optional do we need to append three dots to the end of cutted text
* @return string cutted text
*/

function htmlSubstr($text, $approxLength, $lengthOffset = 20, $cutWords = FALSE, $dotsAtEnd = TRUE) {
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    // $approxLength:
    // The approximate length you want the concatenated text to be

    // $lengthOffset:
    // The variation in how long the text can be in this example text
    // length will be between 200 and 200-20=180 characters and the
    // character where the last tag ends
    // Reset tag counter & quote checker
    $tag_counter = 0;
    $quotes_on = FALSE;

    // Check if the text is too long
    if (mb_strlen($text) > $approxLength) {
        // Reset the tag_counter and pass through (part of) the entire text
        $c = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($text); $i++) {
            // Load the current character and the next one
            // if the string has not arrived at the last character
            $current_char = mb_substr($text,$i,1);
            if ($i < mb_strlen($text) - 1) {
                $next_char = mb_substr($text,$i + 1,1);
            } else {
                $next_char = "";
            }

            // First check if quotes are on
            if (!$quotes_on) {
                // Check if it's a tag
                // On a "<" add 3 if it's an opening tag (like <a href...)
                // or add only 1 if it's an ending tag (like </a>)
                if ($current_char == '<') {
                    if ($next_char == '/') {
                        $tag_counter += 1;
                    } else {
                        $tag_counter += 3;
                    }
                }

                // Slash signifies an ending (like </a> or ... />)
                // substract 2
                if ($current_char == '/' && $tag_counter <> 0) $tag_counter -= 2;
                // On a ">" substract 1
                if ($current_char == '>') $tag_counter -= 1;
                // If quotes are encountered, start ignoring the tags
                // (for directory slashes)
                if ($current_char == '"') $quotes_on = TRUE;
            } else {
                // IF quotes are encountered again, turn it back off
                if ($current_char == '"') $quotes_on = FALSE;
            }

            // Count only the chars outside html tags
            if($tag_counter == 2 || $tag_counter == 0) $c++;

            // Check if the counter has reached the minimum length yet,
            // then wait for the tag_counter to become 0, and chop the string there
            if ($c > $approxLength - $lengthOffset && $tag_counter == 0 && ($next_char == ' ' || $cutWords == TRUE)) {
                $text = mb_substr($text,0,$i + 1);
                if($dotsAtEnd){
                    $text .= '...';
                }

                return $text;
            }
        }
    }
    return $text;
}
```